# transformOrigin triggered from javascript, rotates incorrect

Tags: javascript, css

When using transformOrigin in javascript the rotation does not get correct. Within the settings of transform-origin, I am using X/Y coordinates (100%/50%), since 50% is midpoint per each axis.

**The problem:** When running the animation both the startpoint and endpoint of animation is correct. During the animation the "line indicator" turns in an angle that seems incorrect. If you imagine the animation as it would be a clock, the "line indicator" is clearly leaving its center when rotating.

**Wanted behaviour:** I need the moving "line indictor" to move around the backgrounds red center cross. I am looking for a method of performing the rotating using javascript transformOrigin.

```js
var deg = 180;

function myFunction() {
x = document.getElementById("indicator").style;
x.transform = "rotate(" + deg + "deg)";
x.transformOrigin = "100% 50%"; // Rotate in the center of div.
x.transition = "all 3s";
}
```

```css
.indicator {
  z-index: 3;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: black;
  width: 150px;
  height: 10px;
  margin: 212px 0px 0px 100px;
}

.background-box {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: white;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 50px 0px 0px 100px;
}

#button {
  height: 40px;
  width: 180px;
}


.checkmark-horizontal {
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  width: 300px;
  height: 3px;
  margin: 214px 0px 0px 100px;
}

.checkmark-vertical {
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  width: 3px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 50px 0px 0px 250px;
}
```

```html
<button id = "button" type = "button" name = "button" onclick = "myFunction()">Move indicator 180 degrees </button>

<div class="background-box"></div>

<div id="indicator" class="indicator"></div>

<div class="checkmark-horizontal"></div>
<div class="checkmark-vertical"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set  `transform-origin: 100% 50%;` before setting the transformation or you can use it directly in css

**Edit**

According to other answers it is best to not animate the `transformOrigin` and just animate `transform` in the `transition` property

```js
var deg = 180;

function myFunction() {
  x = document.getElementById("indicator").style;
  x.transformOrigin = "100% 50%"; // Rotate in the center of div.
  x.transition = "transform 3s";
  x.transform = "rotate(" + deg + "deg)";



}
```

```css
.indicator {
  z-index: 3;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: black;
  width: 150px;
  height: 10px;
  margin: 212px 0px 0px 100px;
}

.background-box {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: white;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 50px 0px 0px 100px;
}

#button {
  height: 40px;
  width: 180px;
}

.checkmark-horizontal {
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  width: 300px;
  height: 3px;
  margin: 214px 0px 0px 100px;
}

.checkmark-vertical {
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  width: 3px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 50px 0px 0px 250px;
}
```

```html
<button id="button" type="button" name="button" onclick="myFunction()">Move indicator 180 degrees </button>

<div class="background-box"></div>

<div id="indicator" class="indicator"></div>

<div class="checkmark-horizontal"></div>
<div class="checkmark-vertical"></div>
```

Comment: transform-origin: 100% 50% 0; to make center of the line

Comment: Nice catch @perborin :)

Comment: @Chiller: I updated the question, since I am looking for a solution triggered from javascript using transformOrigin.

Comment: @Toolbox transform origin need to be set before rotation, setting it all together causes the problem,you can resolve the problem by using settimeout , see my update

Comment: @Toolbox as a side note, your value was already correct on the question, no need to add the third value. The issue is only due to the fact that you assign all the values at the same time

Answer (score 1):

In your case you only need to make it `right` BUT the issue is that you are applying the transformation at the same time so it may not take effect.

**UPDATE**

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50745302/8620333) gave the correct reason of the behavior.

```js
var deg = 180;

x = document.getElementById("indicator").style;
x.transformOrigin = "right"; /*set it here before applying the transformation*/

function myFunction() {
  x = document.getElementById("indicator").style;
  x.transform = "rotate(" + deg + "deg)";
  x.transition = "all 3s";
}
```

```css
.indicator {
  z-index: 3;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: black;
  width: 150px;
  height: 10px;
  margin: 212px 0px 0px 100px;
}

.background-box {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: white;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 50px 0px 0px 100px;
}

#button {
  height: 40px;
  width: 180px;
}

.checkmark-horizontal {
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  width: 300px;
  height: 3px;
  margin: 214px 0px 0px 100px;
}

.checkmark-vertical {
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  width: 3px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 50px 0px 0px 250px;
}
```

```html
<button id="button" type="button" name="button" onclick="myFunction()">Move indicator 180 degrees </button>

<div class="background-box"></div>

<div id="indicator" class="indicator"></div>

<div class="checkmark-horizontal"></div>
<div class="checkmark-vertical"></div>
```

Comment: Hey Temani. +1, your solution is nicer than using a Timeout! :)

Answer (score 1):

As you should avoid to use a `Timeout` when not necessary, I propose you to only add the `transition` effect on the `transform` property, like this:

```js
var deg = 180;

function myFunction() {
  x = document.getElementById("indicator").style;
  x.transform = "rotate(" + deg + "deg)";
  x.transformOrigin = "100% 50%";
  x.transition = "transform 3s"; // Don't animate all, only the transform!
}
```

```css
.indicator {
  z-index: 3;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: black;
  width: 150px;
  height: 10px;
  margin: 212px 0px 0px 100px;
}

.background-box {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: white;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 50px 0px 0px 100px;
}

#button {
  height: 40px;
  width: 180px;
}

.checkmark-horizontal {
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  width: 300px;
  height: 3px;
  margin: 214px 0px 0px 100px;
}

.checkmark-vertical {
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  width: 3px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 50px 0px 0px 250px;
}
```

```html
<button id="button" type="button" name="button" onclick="myFunction()">Move indicator 180 degrees </button>

<div class="background-box"></div>

<div id="indicator" class="indicator"></div>

<div class="checkmark-horizontal"></div>
<div class="checkmark-vertical"></div>
```

If you do *need* to animate all, you can use `x.transition = "all 3s, transform-origin 0s";`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: ah, this is what I was looking for intitially :) I was sure it has to do with transition but I didn't get it.